# Content Only being shown in a Single element at a given time

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, contentpresenter

I am Trying to Display a bunch of Names with an Icon in a particular Scroll viewer.
There are 2 main types of Icons that need to be displayed , However although both Types pf Icons are disgustingly being displayed only One Element gets this Icon at a time.

Comment: You should give us some detail on how the Icons are defined...

Comment: Well... how are the icons defined? If you don't know what details are relevant, give us everything you know.

Comment: So... did you try to add `x:Shared="false"` to the `Canvas` resource definition? Thats what your linked Q/A suggests.

Comment: `x:Shared="false"` is for a resource, not for the place of usage... `<Canvas x:Key="FileIcon" x:Shared="false" Width="12" Height="12">`

Comment: So, *where is your resource defined*? For all I can read from the question it *could be* inside a resource dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimal example that verifies, that a resource with `x:Shared="False"` can be used to render multiple occurences of the same icon, while with a shared resource (default), only the last occurence is rendered:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
        x:Class="Application1.MainWindow">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Canvas x:Key="FileIconShared" Width="20" Height="20">
            <Path Stroke="Black" Fill="White"  Data="M20,4L4,4A2,2,0,0,0,2,6L2,18A2,2,0,0,0,4,20L20,20A2,2,0,0,0,22,18L22,6A2,2,0,0,0,20,4 M20,18L4,18 4,8 12,13 20,8 20,18 M20,6L12,11 4,6 4,6 20,6 20,6z">
            </Path>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas x:Key="FileIconNotShared" x:Shared="False" Width="20" Height="20">
            <Path Stroke="Black" Fill="White"  Data="M20,4L4,4A2,2,0,0,0,2,6L2,18A2,2,0,0,0,4,20L20,20A2,2,0,0,0,22,18L22,6A2,2,0,0,0,20,4 M20,18L4,18 4,8 12,13 20,8 20,18 M20,6L12,11 4,6 4,6 20,6 20,6z">
            </Path>
        </Canvas>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="100">
            <TextBlock>Shared 1</TextBlock>
            <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource FileIconShared}"/>
            <TextBlock>Shared 2</TextBlock>
            <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource FileIconShared}"/>
            <TextBlock>Not Shared 1</TextBlock>
            <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource FileIconNotShared}"/>
            <TextBlock>Not Shared 2</TextBlock>
            <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource FileIconNotShared}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Effect: First Icon is missing, 2nd to 4th is rendered.

I can't say how you would apply this to your project, since to much information is missing on where exactly your resources are defined and how exactly your datatemplate is configured.