# Mandatory Use of Setting x:Shared="False" Not Possible

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, contentpresenter

This Question might be Very Similar to Questions such as [Error when using x:Shared="False" resources in external assembly in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22066727/error-when-using-xshared-false-resources-in-external-assembly-in-wpf?rq=1) but I have not been able to find a Solution that I can Relate to or rather get an Idea of How to Solve this.

Why I have mentioned Mandatory Use in the title is I have not been able to find an alternative way to solve my problem other than the with the use of Setting X:shared to false.

My problem is that in a particular view that has Icons , for Elements of Similar Type Icons seem to be sharing hence even if there are two or more types the Icon will only be rendered with one Item

This Question is justified in these Stack oveerflow Questions as well

[Content Only being shown in a Single element at a given time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57602338/content-only-being-shown-in-a-single-element-at-a-given-time)

[WPF: Can use StaticResource only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45154572/wpf-can-use-staticresource-only-once)

I would Really appreciate any help/suggestions to overcome this

Comment: One Way to Avoid x:Shared Entirely Would Be to Use DataTemplates For Your Icons. Write A DataTemplate Which Displays The Icon, And Then To Display The icon, you Can Use A usercontrol Like so: `<UserControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource HomeIconTemplate}" />`, where `HomeIconTemplate` is the `x:Key` Value For THe DataTemplate In Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might look at using DataTemplates to create the icons, if for any reason x:Shared is a problem. A DataTemplate instantiates a copy of the content when it's applied, so sharing is a non-issue.

Resource:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="FileSystemIcon">
    <Canvas Width="12" Height="12">
        <Path 
            Stroke="Black" 
            Fill="White"  
            Data="M20,4L4,4A2,2,0,0,0,2,6L2,18A2,2,0,0,0,4,20L20,20A2,2,0,0,0,22,18L22,6A2,2,0,0,0,20,4 M20,18L4,18 4,8 12,13 20,8 20,18 M20,6L12,11 4,6 4,6 20,6 20,6z" 
            />
    </Canvas>
</DataTemplate>
```

Usage:

```
<UserControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource FileSystemIcon}" />
```

Comment: Hi Ed , This was a great solution and It did get the job done .
If time permits you would really appreciate your help on this Question as well 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57620004/content-control-xname-not-disgustingly-being-picked-up-by-target-name-is-data-t

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

A complication is the numerous colours you have there. The trend nowadays is to simpler icons with just a background and foreground. Which you can "just" use one path and geometry for.

Seeing as how this is several shapes and several colours, you could use a DrawingImage.

I did this example in a usercontrol, it's roughly like one of your icons.

```
       xmlns:PresentationOptions="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/options" 
        mc:Ignorable="PresentationOptions"
                 >
        <UserControl.Resources>
            <DrawingImage x:Key='icon'  PresentationOptions:Freeze="True">
                <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                    <DrawingGroup>
                        <DrawingGroup.Children>
                            <GeometryDrawing Geometry="M17,17A5,5,0,0,1,12,22A5,5,0,0,1,7,17C7,15.36,7.79,13.91,9,13L9,5A3,3,0,0,1,12,2A3,3,0,0,1,15,5L15,13C16.21,13.91,17,15.36,17,17 M11,8L11,14.17C9.83,14.58,9,15.69,9,17A3,3,0,0,0,12,20A3,3,0,0,0,15,17C15,15.69,14.17,14.58,13,14.17L13,8 11,8z"
                                             Brush="Wheat"
                                             >
                                <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                    <Pen Thickness="1" Brush="Green"/>
                                </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                            </GeometryDrawing>
                            <GeometryDrawing Geometry="M17,18L12,15.82 7,18 7,5 17,5 M17,3L7,3A2,2,0,0,0,5,5L5,21 12,18 19,21 19,5C19,3.89,18.1,3,17,3z"
                                             Brush="Lavender"
                                             >
                                <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                    <Pen Thickness="1" Brush="Red"/>
                                </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                            </GeometryDrawing>
                        </DrawingGroup.Children>
                    </DrawingGroup>
                </DrawingImage.Drawing>
            </DrawingImage>
        </UserControl.Resources>
        <Grid>
            <StackPanel>
                <Image  Width="12" Height="12" Source="{StaticResource icon}"/>
                <Image  Width="12" Height="12" Source="{StaticResource icon}"/>
            </StackPanel>

        </Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

Comment: Hi Andy , These colors were used to just get a diversity in the output
Thnk you for your answer I will give a try down this road :)